# ImportError: No module named common

Tags: python

My project has two dirs `common` and `core`.

```
root
 |----common
 |       |-----__init__.py
 |       |-----util.py
 |
 |------core
         |-----__init__.py
         |------iemoji.py
```

In root, I execute `python core/iemoji.py`, an error occurs.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   
>  File "core/iemoji.py", line 6, in module
>      
> from common import util
>   
> ImportError: No module named common

I import utils.py like this:

```
from common import util
```

Comment: what is common's `__init__.py`?

Comment: It's empty and it's created by Pycharm (a python ide).

Comment: A module is a file, not a directory. You should be saying 'from utils' instead.

Comment: @CoXier your setup should be fine like it is, I have just tested it myself. Have you tried Alasdair's answer (print(sys.path))?

Comment: Yes I print(sys.path) and I see the first item is my root `/Users/myname/project/core`.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You stated that core was a subfolder of root, please clarify

Comment: I am not familiar with python. I do not know whether it's right way to test it. I directly `print(sys.path)` before `from common import util`.

Comment: No, what I meant is: In your question it looks like you have a root folder and then inside is a folder `core` and `common`. So you should have `root/common` and `root/core`. Now you say that `/Users/myname/project/core` is your `root` so I am confused what your actual folder structure is

Comment: Do you have a `/Users/myname/project/core/core` and `/Users/myname/project/core/common`?

Comment: `/Users/myname/project/core`  means `/Users/myname/root/core`.

Comment: Then the whole problem was that you were inside the core folder. You should have been inside the root folder and calling `python core/iemoji.py`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166763/discussion-between-coxier-and-flyingteller).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `/path/to/root/` is not on your python path when you call `python core/emoji.py`. You can check by printing `sys.path` in your script.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

You could add the root directory to your python path by setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/root python core/emoji.py
```

or you could set it in your script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/root')
```

Comment: I do not know why I can do like this in other project.

Comment: In your other project you must be importing things that are on the python path. Comparing the layout of your projects and the output of `sys.path` might help you figure out what the difference is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why `/path/to/root/ is not on your python path` ?

Comment: Why should it be on your python path? If you look the output of `print(sys.path)`, you'll see that the script's directory `/path/to/root/core` is on the python path. There's nothing in Python that's going to magically add parent directories to the python path as well.

Comment: this is a very bad practice

Comment: @alex I understand if you don’t like modifying `sys.path` but if you don’t explain why or suggest a different approach it doesn’t really help future readers

Answer (score 3):

Set up your `__init__.py`s to point to the modules in their respective folders.

common's `__init__.py`:

```
from . import util
```

core's `__init__.py`:

```
from . import emoji
```

Then you should be able to call it with:

```
from common import util
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I am sorry. It's `util.py` rather than `utils.py`. I made a mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Yes I have checked it.

Answer (score 2):

add this **export PYTHONPATH="$PWD"** before **python core/iemoji.py**

Answer (score 0):

pip install common, use this command and install the package by using pip.

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to the question. Please read questions carefully before trying to post any answers.

Comment: The OP is not referring to a package on PyPI called `common`, (s)he is referring to a local library of a software project.